# SharePoint Online Calculated Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, choice-field

I am trying to create a formula that will auto-populate a column based on the input from two other columns. The auto population would need to check the boxes of the appropriate items that apply based on the input.

Example:

Column A - Flight Type:

- Orientation
- Spouse
- Private

Column B - Aircraft type:

- Airbus 100
- Airbus 200
- Airbus 300

Depending on the selection of Column A and B I would like C to auto-populate required tasks from 10 choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column with conditions based on two columns like:

```
=IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Orientation", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 100"), "Task 1", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Orientation", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 200"), "Task 2", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Orientation", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 300"), "Task 3", "")))
```

Similarly, you can add conditions for other choices of `Flight Type` & `Aircraft type`

Final formula should be something like:

```
=IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Orientation", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 100"), "Task 1", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Orientation", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 200"), "Task 2", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Orientation", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 300"), "Task 3", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Spouse", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 100"), "Task 4", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Spouse", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 200"), "Task 5", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Spouse", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 300"), "Task 6", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Private", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 100"), "Task 7", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Private", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 200"), "Task 8", IF(AND([Flight Type] = "Private", [Aircraft type] = "Airbus 300"), "Task 9", "Default Task")))))))))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Set **The data type returned from this formula is:** to **Single line of text** in column settings.

**Documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))